# Read cells and preserve line breaks

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I have an excel file with line breaks inside the cells. I like to import the data into a database using phpspreadsheet.

I have to split the line at the line break, as there are separate values for the database.

It seems, that the retrieved cell value trims the line breaks.

I use following code to import cells into rows.

```
        $rows = array();
        foreach ($sheetData->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
            $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE); 
            $cells = [];
            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                $cells[] = $cell->getValue();
            }
           $rows[] = $cells;
        }
```

Is there a setting to preserve line breaks?

Answer (score 0):

The line break is inside the string represented as `chr(10)`. So I have to explode the string using `chr(10)`.